# Focus and Select All on textarea text when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I have a textarea and I want its text to have the focus and selected-all when the page is loaded. This is my code, but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
<body onload="document.formIn.originalScript.select();document.formIn.originalScript.focus();">
<form action="servlet" method="POST" name="formIn">
<textarea name="originalScript" cols="52" rows="30">This is my text</textarea>
```

Thanks

**FIXED:** See my answer below. Works on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I upload the code on the original question to the server, it works. It is only locally where I get these issues.

Answer (score 0):

try paste this in the end of body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

            onLoad();

            function onLoad() {
                 document.getElementsByName('originalScript')[0].select();

            }

        </script>
```